# Azure AD B2C sign up policy additional emails

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to get Azure AD B2C to store alternate emails so we can help recover the account?  I am using a signup policy that is based on a local account.  I am not using username, I'm using "email" as the identifier.

Even though I specify the local account type as email and also specify a signup claim of email, it only let's me put in one email.  I can see how that might make sense.

I tried just storing an additional email in one of the existing graph fields, but it said that was read only.

Along those lines, is it possible to have more than one email listed in the `signInName` array?

TIA